# ¿Por que no me imprime en otros "case" mi arreglo de objetos en JAVA?

Tags: java, switch

Es un código sobre una farmacia, lo que hace (Después de encapsular las clases) es, pedir datos sobre los diferentes medicamentos (pastilla, jarabe, pomada).

"Corroboro" que los datos sí están siendo guardados en el arreglo cuando hago un `println` en el código después de haber creado el objeto, pero, a la hora de irme a otro `case` (Específicamente case 6) no hay datos en el arreglo.

Al principio me salía que era un error de tipo *NPE* el cual pude resolver haciendo un `if` con el `null`, pero ahora no me da como devolución ningún valor.

```
//CLASE POMADA
GETTER AND SETTER DEL CODIGO
//CLASE JARABE
GETTER AND SETTER DEL CODIGO
```

````
//CLASE PASTILLA
package com.mycompany.farmacia;

/**
 *
 * @author motam
 */
public class Pastillas extends Medicinas {
    
    private int tabletas= 0;
    private int miligramosP= 0;

    public Pastillas(String nombre, String laboratorio, int codBarras, double precio, int dia, int mes, int anio,int tabletas, int miligramosP) {
        super(nombre, laboratorio, codBarras, precio, dia, mes, anio);
        this.tabletas = tabletas;
        this.miligramosP = miligramosP;
    }
    
    public int getTabletas() {
        return tabletas;
    }

    public void setTabletas(int tabletas) {
        this.tabletas = tabletas;
    }

    public int getMiligramosP() {
        return miligramosP;
    }

    public void setMiligramosP(int miligramosP) {
        this.miligramosP = miligramosP;
    }
    
}
//CLASE MEDICINA
package com.mycompany.farmacia;

/**
 *
 * @author motam
 */
public class Medicinas {
    private String nombre = "";          //Encapsulando datos
    private String laboratorio = "";     //Encapsulando datos
    private int codBarras = 0;          //Encapsulando datos
    private double precio = 0;
    int dia= 0;
    int mes= 0;
    int anio= 0;

    public Medicinas(String nombre, String laboratorio, int codBarras, double precio, int dia, int mes, int anio) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.laboratorio = laboratorio;
        this.codBarras = codBarras;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.dia = dia;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.anio = anio;
    }

   

    public int getDia() {
        return dia;
    }

    public void setDia(int dia) {
        this.dia = dia;
    }

    public int getMes() {
        return mes;
    }

    public void setMes(int mes) {
        this.mes = mes;
    }

    public int getAnio() {
        return anio;
    }

    public void setAnio(int anio) {
        this.anio = anio;
    }
    
    public double getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(double precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getLaboratorio() {
        return laboratorio;
    }

    public void setLaboratorio(String laboratorio) {
        this.laboratorio = laboratorio;
    }

    public int getCodBarras() {
        return codBarras;
    }

    public void setCodBarras(int codBarras) {
        this.codBarras = codBarras;
    }

    
    
}
//CLASE MAIN
package com.mycompany.farmacia;

import java.util.Calendar;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author motam
 */
public class Farmacia {
        
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int contPastillas = 0;
        int contJarabes = 0;
        int contPomadas = 0;
        int contBuffer = 0;
        Scanner t = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner dec = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean salir = false;
        while(!salir){
            System.out.println("BIENVENIDO AL MENU DE LA FARMACIA");
        System.out.println("Seleccione de nuestro menu su opcion. ");
        System.out.println("1) Ingresar un medicamento. ");
        System.out.println("2) Borrar un medicamento. ");
        System.out.println("3) Modificar el precio de unas pastillas. ");
        System.out.println("4) Modificar el precio de un jarabe. ");
        System.out.println("5) Modificar el precio de una pomada. ");
        System.out.println("6) Imprimir la lista de todas las pastillas con precio.");
        System.out.println("7) Imprimir la lista de todos los jarabes con precio. ");
        System.out.println("8) Imprimir la lista de todas las pomadas con precio.");
        System.out.println("9) Imprimir Resumen de medicamentos (número de pastillas, jarabes y pomadas).");
        System.out.println("10) Buscar un producto por nombre e imprimir toda su información.");
        System.out.println("11) Buscar un producto por código de barras e imprimir toda su información.");
        System.out.println("12) Salir");
        int decision = dec.nextInt();
        
        Pastillas[] pastillas = new Pastillas[100];
        Jarabes[] jarabes = new Jarabes[80];
        Pomadas[] pomadas = new Pomadas[40];
       
        
        switch (decision) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("¿Qué clase de medicamento desea introducir?");
                System.out.println("1) Pastillas ");
                System.out.println("2) Jarabes ");
                System.out.println("3) Pomadas ");
                
                int tipo = dec.nextInt();
                    switch(tipo){
                        case 1:
                            contPastillas++;
                            System.out.println("BIENVENIDO A LA ALTA DE PASTILLAS");
                            
                            System.out.println("CONTADOR DE PASTILLAS EN " + contPastillas);
                           // System.out.println("Introduzca en este orden su medicamento");
                            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                            System.out.println("Nombre del medicamento");
                            if(contBuffer>=1){
                                t.nextLine();
                                contBuffer=0;
                                
                            }
                                String nomb = t.next();//CARGANDO EL NOMBRE EN STRING
                            System.out.println("Laboratorio del medicamento o Generico");
                            if(contBuffer>=1){
                                t.nextLine();
                                contBuffer=0;
                                
                            }
                                String lab = t.next();//CARGANDO EL LABORATORIO EN STRING
                            System.out.println("Codigo de barras en numeros enteros");
                                int codb = t.nextInt(); //CARGANDO EL CODIGO DE BARRAS CON ENTEROS
                            System.out.println("Precio al publico");
                                double price = t.nextDouble(); //CARGANDO EL PRECIO EN FLOTANTE
                            System.out.println("Fecha de caducidad");
                                System.out.println("Introduce el dia que caduca");
                                int day = t.nextInt();
                                System.out.println("Introduzca el mes donde caduca");
                                int month = t.nextInt();
                                System.out.println("Introduzca el año donde caduca");
                                int year =t.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("Numero de tabletas en caja");
                                int tablet = t.nextInt(); //CARGANDO EL NUMERO DE TABLETAS EN ENTERO                          
                            System.out.println("Los miligramos de las pastillas");
                                int mili = t.nextInt();//CARGANDO EL NUMERO DE MILIGRAMOS EN ENTERO
                            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                            
                            pastillas[contPastillas] = new Pastillas(nomb, lab, codb, price, day, month, year, tablet, mili);
                           System.out.println("Nombre: " + pastillas[contPastillas].getNombre() + "  Laboratorio: " + pastillas[contPastillas].getLaboratorio() + "  Codigo de barras: " + pastillas[contPastillas].getCodBarras()+ "  Precio: " + pastillas[contPastillas].getPrecio() + "  Fecha de caducidad: " + pastillas[contPastillas].getDia() + " / " + pastillas[contPastillas].getMes() + " / " + pastillas[contPastillas].getAnio() + "  Numero de tabletas: " + pastillas[contPastillas].getTabletas() + "  Miligramos :" + pastillas[contPastillas].getMiligramosP());
                           
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            contJarabes++;
                            System.out.println("BIENVENIDO A LA ALTA DE JARABES");
                            
                            System.out.println("CONTADOR DE JARABES EN " + contJarabes);
                           // System.out.println("Introduzca en este orden su medicamento");
                            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                            System.out.println("Nombre del medicamento");
                            if(contBuffer>=1){
                                t.nextLine();
                                contBuffer=0;
                                
                            }
                                nomb = t.next();//CARGANDO EL NOMBRE EN STRING
                                contBuffer++;
                            System.out.println("Laboratorio del medicamento o Generico");
                            if(contBuffer>=1){
                                t.nextLine();
                                contBuffer=0;
                                
                            }
                                lab = t.nextLine();//CARGANDO EL LABORATORIO EN STRING
                                contBuffer++;
                            System.out.println("Codigo de barras en numeros enteros");
                                codb = t.nextInt(); //CARGANDO EL CODIGO DE BARRAS CON ENTEROS
                            System.out.println("Precio al publico");
                                price = t.nextDouble(); //CARGANDO EL PRECIO EN FLOTANTE
                            System.out.println("Fecha de caducidad");
                            System.out.println("Introduce el dia que caduca");
                                 day= t.nextInt();
                                System.out.println("Introduzca el mes donde caduca");
                                 month= t.nextInt();
                                System.out.println("Introduzca el año donde caduca");
                                 year=t.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("Mililitros del jarabe");
                                int ml = t.nextInt(); //Cargando los mililitros del jarabe                         
                            System.out.println("¿Trae o no trae vaso?");
                                String v = t.next(); //Cargando si tiene o no vasito
                                
                            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                            
                            jarabes[contJarabes]= new Jarabes(nomb, lab, codb, price, day, month, year, ml, v);
                           System.out.println("Nombre: " + jarabes[contJarabes].getNombre() + "  Laboratorio: " + jarabes[contJarabes].getLaboratorio() + "  Codigo de barras: " + jarabes[contJarabes].getCodBarras()+ "  Precio: " + jarabes[contJarabes].getPrecio() + "  Fecha de caducidad: " + jarabes[contJarabes].getDia() + " / " + jarabes[contJarabes].getMes() + " / " + jarabes[contJarabes].getAnio() + "  Mililitros de jarabe: " + jarabes[contJarabes].getMililitrosF() + "  ¿Trae vasito? :" + jarabes[contJarabes].getVaso());
                           contBuffer++;
                           
                           break;
                        case 3:
                            contPomadas++;
                            System.out.println("BIENVENIDO A LA ALTA DE POMADAS");
                            
                            System.out.println("CONTADOR DE JARABES EN " + contPomadas);
                           // System.out.println("Introduzca en este orden su medicamento");
                            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                            System.out.println("Nombre del medicamento");
                            if(contBuffer>=1){
                                t.nextLine();
                                contBuffer=0;
                                
                            }
                                nomb = t.next();//CARGANDO EL NOMBRE EN STRING
                                contBuffer++;
                            System.out.println("Laboratorio del medicamento o Generico");
                            if(contBuffer>=1){
                                t.nextLine();
                                contBuffer=0;
                                
                            }
                                lab = t.next();//CARGANDO EL LABORATORIO EN STRING
                                contBuffer++;
                            System.out.println("Codigo de barras en numeros enteros");
                                codb = t.nextInt(); //CARGANDO EL CODIGO DE BARRAS CON ENTEROS
                            System.out.println("Precio al publico");
                                price = t.nextDouble(); //CARGANDO EL PRECIO EN FLOTANTE
                            System.out.println("Fecha de caducidad");
                                System.out.println("Introduzca el dia de la caducidad");
                                day= t.nextInt();
                                System.out.println("Introduzca el mes donde caduca");
                                month= t.nextInt();
                                System.out.println("Introduzca el año donde caduca");
                                 year=t.nextInt();
                                 //System.out.println(day + " / " +month +" / "+ year);
                            System.out.println("Gramos en el tubo de pomada");
                                int gramos = t.nextInt(); //Cargando los mililitros del jarabe  
                                System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                           pomadas[contPomadas]= new Pomadas(nomb, lab, codb, price, day, month, year, gramos);
                            System.out.println("Nombre: " + pomadas[contPomadas].getNombre() + "  Laboratorio: " + pomadas[contPomadas].getLaboratorio() + "  Codigo de barras: " + pomadas[contPomadas].getCodBarras()+ "  Precio: " + pomadas[contPomadas].getPrecio() + "  Fecha de caducidad: " + pomadas[contPomadas].getDia() + " / " + pomadas[contPomadas].getMes() + " / " + pomadas[contPomadas].getAnio() + "  Gramos de pomada: " + pomadas[contPomadas].getGramos());
                            
                            break;
                    }
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:  
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("Estas son todas las pastillas");
                    for(int i=1;i<=contPastillas;i++){ 
                        if(pastillas[i]!=null){
                            System.out.println("Nombre: " + pastillas[i].getNombre() + "  Laboratorio: " + pastillas[i].getLaboratorio() + "  Precio: " + pastillas[i].getPrecio());
                        }   
                    }     
                break;
            case 7:
                break;
            case 8:
                break;     
            case 9:
                break;
            case 10:
                break;
            case 11:
                break;
                
            case 12:
                System.out.println("¡Le deseamos buena salud!");
                salir=true;
                break;
        }
        }```
````

Comment: Hola Marco Antonio, declarando pastillas, jarabes y pomadas antes de entrar en el `while`, tu código funciona, al declararlas dentro, con cada iteración las reseteas, por lo que al elegir la opción "6", siempre estarán vacías, ahora bien, hay algo en tu código que... me choca,  así como está, solo puedes almacenar "99" pastillas, ya que empiezas a guardar pastillas desde la posición "1" del array, está bien que compensaste en la impresión, recorriendo a partir de esa posición, pero no me parece la forma adecuada... aunque  funciona!.

Comment: @MarcePuente Muchisimas gracias, es un error tan bobo que no lo vi
Tomare tu consejo en cuenta sobre los arreglos, lo solía hacer así pero se me quedó una mala  manía. ¡Mil gracias!

Comment: Un placer ayudarte, y créeme, nos pasa a todos!!.